# How to substitute shell variable into screen's "stuff" command in Bash?

Tags: bash, variables, screen

I have script that needs to resume Virtualbox machines, and would like to use machine name as a variable so I have:

```
VMN="VMtest"
screen -S MyScr -p 3 -X stuff $'VBoxManage controlvm "${VMN}" resume --type headless\n'
```

but variable is not visible in this command. So I only see following command in screen window

```
[me@srv ~]$ VBoxManage controlvm resume --type headless
```

So I'm not sure if variable needs to be defined in that screen first or how to carry it inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

screen's `stuff` understands `\n` so you can use double quotes for the command:

```
VMN="VMtest"
screen -S MyScr -p 3 -X stuff "VBoxManage controlvm $VMN resume --type headless\n"
```

The following also works:

```
# CTRL-J
... stuff "VBoxManage controlvm $VMN resume --type headless^J"
# \ooo (octal)
... stuff "VBoxManage controlvm $VMN resume --type headless\012"
```

Comment: Thanks @pynexj  I actually wasn't exact `"$VMN"` should be in double quotes, so I'm not sure how to then use it `sfuff` with double qoutes, but it actually works even without quoting the `VM name`.  Thanks

Comment: if the vm name includes chars like SPACE you can write `... stuff "VBoxManage controlvm '$VMN' resume --type headless\n`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no parameter expansion taking place inside `$' .... '`, but you can always catenate the pieces into a single string:

```
"VBoxManage controlvm ${VMN} resume --type headless"$'\n'
```

Comment: @DenisZ: I nearly never ever used `Screen`, but why do you need _-X stuff_ here? Wouldn't be `screen -S MyScr -p 3 VBoxManage controlvm "${VMN}" resume --type headless` sufficient?

Comment: How would I solve this issue if `$VMN` should be surrounded with double quotes, like it is in my question?

Comment: @DenisZ : I don't know VBoxManage, but i would be very surprised, if it wants to see double quotes passed to the _controlvm_ command; but if it does, just write them: `controlvm \""$VMN"\" resume ....`. You just have to escape them to avoid them being eaten by the shell. `screen` for sure doesn't need them (unless you are using _-X stuff_ of course).

Comment: Thanks @user1934428 for an update.  I use `-X stuff` because I have already running screens, and sometimes I have to go into particular window and pause or resume VM.  I didn't find any other way to do it.  I know technically I could just run directly `VBoxManage ...` as a user, but when I run it in existing screen I also see some history when I enter screen manually so it's more transparent to me. (I also insert date) above each command so I know when it was done.